# How to hide a status bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, statusbar

I can hide a status bar in my app:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

When I chose my launch image and start it first time, it's status bar over a picture. How can I hide this?

Comment: I created a `BaseViewController` and added this code to it's `viewDidLoad`. This makes sure that I have it applied to all my view controllers. I also added `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` under `Info`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Add the following code to your view controller:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
    // iOS 7
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
} else {
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Must add a key UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to Infor.plist and set value to YES. Then can hide/show status bar.

Comment: in what part of my view controller should I add the if-else statement?

Comment: Hate iOS for this! Why do we need **cking Status Bar property in Simulated Metrics????

Answer (score 132):

You need to add this code in your AppDelegate file, not in your Root View Controller

Or add the property **Status bar is initially hidden** in your plist file

[image]

Folks, in **iOS 7+**

please add this to your info.plist file, It will make the difference :)

UIStatusBarHidden

UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance

[image]

For iOS **11.4+ and Xcode 9.4 +**

Use this code either in one or all your view controllers

> override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
>        return true    }

Comment: This is not working for me on iOS 11.4 + Xcode 9.4 beta.

Answer (score 66):

What helped me is this (changing plist file):

1. set **Status bar is initially hidden = YES**
2. add row: **View controller-based status bar appearance = NO**

[image: Hide StatusBar - plist settings]

Answer (score 42):

Put this code to your view controller in which you hide status bar:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {return YES;}
```

Comment: beware, this will work on ios7 only: - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);

Answer (score 12):

In iOS 7 status bar appearance depends on `UIViewController` as default. To hide status bar globally, in `info.plist` use `NO` value for `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` key and use `UIApplication`'s `setStatusBarHidden` method with `YES` `BOOL` value.

Comment: in my game bottom left has a white ball. How can I remove it?

Comment: doesn't work when you are using a UIImagePickerController. It shows back the status bar whenever you show it and the statusbar doesn't hide back ever...

Comment: Even the solution I gave doesn't work few times and I am assuming it as a bug.

Comment: To hide the status bar, I used setStatusBarHidden = YES

Comment: @Jon The answer had YES, but the editor made a mistake I guess.

Answer (score 12):

add this key key from dropdownlist in "info.plist" and voila you will no more see top bar that includes elements something like GSM,wifi icon etc.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me ,

Add below code into the info.plist file ,

```
 <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
 <false/>
 <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
 <false/>
```

Hopes this is work for some one .

Answer (score 1):

In `info.plist`

```
View controller-based status bar appearance NO
Status bar is initially hidden YES
```

In `view controller.m`

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to have a handy note... I come to this link almost once in a week to copy code snippet... then I have to search all different answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am supporting iOS 5, 6, & 7.  My app is iPad only. I needed to use all of the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

View Controller:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{ return YES; }
```

Info.plist

```
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <string>YES</string>

    <key>UIStatusBarHidden~ipad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <string>NO</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the box on Targets/Summary iPad Deployment Info and you status bar will disappear.
It works on my apps.

Comment: On ios 7 and xcode 5, Take a look at this post, it saved my job. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but its an easy fix! Just set

```
status bar is initially hidden = YES
```

then add an row by clicking on the plus right after the text `status bar is initially hidden`, then set the text to

```
view controller-based status bar appearance
```

by clicking the arrows, and set it to `NO`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way that I do it is by typing the following into the .m file.

```
- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low quality, can you please update your answer to describe why this works?

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution in swift, in your view controller

```
// you can use your own logic to determine if you need to hide status bar
// I just put a var here for now
var hideStatusBar = false
override func preferStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return hideStatus
}


// in other method to manually toggle status bar
func updateUI() {
    hideStatusBar = true
    // call this method to update status bar
    prefersStatusBarHidden()
}
```

Comment: As of Xcode 8.1 there seems to be no function preferStatusBarHidden to override. Instead the line "let preferStatusBarHidden : Bool = true" in ViewController did it for me. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

To hide status bar for each individual view controller programmatically, use any of the following two procedures:

### Procedure 1:

```swift
[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

### Procedure 2:

```swift
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

To hide status bar for the entire application, we should follow the given below procedure:

You should add this value to plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to "NO".

[Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSxcK.png)