# Hide UINavigationBar but still show Status Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

How can I hide the navigation bar by not hiding the status bar in my app? When I try `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];` it also hides the status bar. I need to show the status bar like this:

[image]

I need to first hide a visible navigation bar, make the status bar still visible and I also have a view that I need to move below the status bar, but the view is being positioned like the navigation bar is still there when I set the frame's position to 0,0.

I setup my statusbar as:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Comment: did you set in your plist as viewcontroller based statusbar hidden yes

Comment: no it is
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO;

I also have:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

Comment: This link may help you to fix this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915092/ios7-status-bar-hide-show-on-select-controllers

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code where you want to hide the navigation bar

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

Comment: Please check if you have correctly designed in your interface file.

Comment: I tried this but it also hides the status bar. What I want is to have atleast the effect in Facebook where when the navigationbar is hidden, the status bar still has a colored background.

Comment: Call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide navigation bar but show status bar, you should set **Top Space to Top Layout Guide** as 0 instead of -44.  and then

[Hide navigation bar in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075417/navigation-bar-hidden-not-working-ios): `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]`

I start to set top space as -44, then call method `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the status bar text and symbols were not shown because they had the same color as the background (black). I solved the problem by changing the background color:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.superview setBackgroundColor:UIColor.whiteColor];
```