# Status bar disappears after launch on iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm experiencing weird behaviour of the status bar visibility. I just changed the code to use ViewController-based status bar appearance, setting `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in the project Info section. After doing that, the status bar completely disappears after the launch phase on iOS 9 (On iOS 10, everything works as expected). Overriding `prefersStatusBarHidden` does not help:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        }
    }
```

the status bar is still invisible. I use a UITabBarController containing a UINavigationController and the `prefersStatusBarHidden` of the top ViewController inside the UINavigationController is called and returns false. Still the status bar is only visible for the launch and then disappears when the root view is shown.
Has anyone experienced this or similar behaviour? I looked for other calls that might affect this, but I can't find anything.

Comment: What do you set for `Hide Status Bar` in project settings under `Deployment Info` section ? Try setting it to *unchecked* ?

Comment: It's already unchecked.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915092/ios7-status-bar-hide-show-on-select-controllers

Comment: How does that link help me?

Comment: Did you check the first answer's case related to tab bar?