# Swift UIApplication.setStatusBarStyle Doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uistatusbar

Here's my implementation in a subclass of `UIViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)
}
```

I tried putting it in AppDelegate initialisation code (using the passed in UIApplication instance), however the status bar is still black..

Is this a bug with iOS 8 or am I doing it wrong?

Note: I may be breaking someone's law's here by discussing ios 8.. Its a general problem that, when compiled doesn't work for ios 7 either.

Update: Still doesn't work, even with value in Info.plist and code in `- didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
[image: Nope still doesn't work]

Comment: In the settings (`info.plist`) add `View Controller-Based Status Bar Appearance` and set it to `false`

Comment: @JackWu Added to `Info.plist` but no go

Comment: After you set that try calling  `UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)` in the app delegate's `applicationDidLoad`. It should work...

Comment: @JackWu Hmmmmm, still doesn't work :/

Comment: Which good soul downvoted?

Comment: Try the normal stuff... Clean.. Restart Xcode...also make sure it's the right info.plist...not a different target.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I hide the status bar in a Swift iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236912/how-to-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-a-swift-ios-app)

Comment: @drewag I don't want to hide the status bar, but change its colour from `dark -> light`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You really should implement `preferredStatusBarStyle` on your view controller(s):

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}
```

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to Info.plist file
2. Hover on one of those lines and a (+) and (-)
   button will show up.
3. Click the plus button to add new key Type in
   start with capital **V** and automatically the first choice will be *View 
   controller-based status bar appearance*.
4. Add that as the KEY.
5. Set the VALUE to "NO"
6. Go to you AppDelegate.swift
7. Add the following code, inside the method

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)

    return true
}
```

8. **DONE! Run your app and your status bar is now WHITE!**

Comment: Nice. I figured it out using the comments though. Both answers are correct (currently accepted answer + this answer)

Comment: UIApplication's "setStatusBarStyle" method is deprecated as of iOS 9.  Overriding "preferredStatusBarStyle" seems to be the preferred way to change the status bar text color.