# Cannot set iOS Status Bar Colour for View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard, uistatusbar

I am developing an app for **iOS8**, using **Swift 1.2**.

However, I am having an issue with the colour of the status bar (the one with the time, battery indicator etc).

In my `Info.plist` file, I have `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` set to `YES` as well as `Status bar style` set to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` and then in all my view controllers in the Storyboard, I have the status bar set to "Light Content".

[image]

This works for all of my `NavigationViewControllers` and views embedded within `NavigationViewControllers`, however I have one normal `TableViewController` which is not embedded in a `NavigationController`, and when I push this view modally, the status bar changes to BLACK!???

Even when I look at the view in the Storyboard editor it shows as a white status bar (note the faint white battery indicator at the right of the below screenshot):

[image]

But when I build and run on my iPhone, the status bar shows as black...

Why is this? How can I fix this? I don't know what could be incorrect.

Comment: Add one more key `Status bar style` -> `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`

Comment: Yep already have that (sorry, didn't mention in the question, but already have that too)

Comment: Managed to find the solution on another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622960/swift-uiapplication-setstatusbarstyle-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution to this was very easy, from another StackOverflow article ([Swift UIApplication.setStatusBarStyle Doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622960/swift-uiapplication-setstatusbarstyle-doesnt-work)).

For anyone else wanting to set the status bar colour programmatically, I just inserted the following code into my ViewController for the view in question:

### - Swift 4.0+

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent        
}
```

### - Earlier Swifts (4.0-)

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure to add `View controller-based status bar appearance` (UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance) with value `NO` to your Info.plist

Comment: I have it set to YES...why should I set it to NO?

When I previously had it as NO, I had a different issue where the status bar would be white, but then when I would display a UIImagePicker and then dismissed the picker, the status bar would from then on always be black throughout the app (which is not correct...needs to be white)

Comment: When you have YES, every controller can use its own style. When you set it to NO, the setting from the plist is always used.

Answer (score 2):

These are setups for `UIStatusBar` style:

1. Go to `AppDelegate.swift` in that add below code line in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

   ```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
   ```
2. Add below keys into `.plist` file.

[image]

3. In Storyboard select your controller `UINavigationController` or `UIViewController`. And set status bar style as `Light Content`

[image]

Comment: The option to select status bar in storyboard is in fact no longer possible.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 3**

in your `AppDelegate.swift` file in function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
```

Answer (score 0):

add this Line in your `Appdelegate.swift` file :

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```