# How to fix table view's search bar overlapping with status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, statusbar

I have a UITableViewController inside a navigation controller, with a search bar. This is how I add the search bar in viewDidLoad:

```
let resultsController = SearchTableViewController()
resultsController.people = people
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
searchBar.placeholder = "Search a person"
searchBar.sizeToFit()
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
```

This is the result:

[image]

I tried editing the table view in the storyboard to add a constraint to make it further from the top view's margins, but I can't add contraints, probably because the table view is inside a UITableViewController.

Comment: best solution. create new uiview, leave 20 pixels from top and add uisearchbar inside that headerview and assign whole view as tableheaderview, your problem will resolved.

Comment: I don't find you have embeded your uitableviewcontroller inside a uinavigationcontroller. From storyboard you can do it by just selecting the view controller and going to Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Comment: It is already in a navigation controller, I can clearly see it from the storyboard file: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=768cf89e7cf13325!4438&authkey=!AKP0Wbsec7-Zo-g&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need this code.

In your `viewDidLoad` method add this code:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)
```

And your tableview will be something like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

You can forcely scroll table with this code:

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath( NSIndexPath(index: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
```

Comment: This way when I launch the app I still see the table view and the status bar overlapped, but if I scroll it it gets fixed. Watch this video: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=768cf89e7cf13325!4440&authkey=!ANbvmk8nT8NLO5I&ithint=video%2cmov

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri try adding tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath( NSIndexPath(index: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are writing code in swift but this is how you would hide status bar in objectiveC

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        // iOS 7
        [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    } else {
        // iOS 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
}

// Add this Method
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Here's an answer in swift [How do I hide the status bar in a Swift iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236912/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-a-swift-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put following code in **didFinishLaunching** in **AppDelegate** class

in swift -

```
    var version = ( UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString ).floatValue

   if (version >= 7) {
        application.setStatusBarStyle(  UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true);
        window?.clipsToBounds = true;
        window?.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window!.frame.size.width,self.window!.frame.size.height-20);
    }
```

in Objective-c -

```
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
        self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
        self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
    }
```

and add following method in your **ViewController** class-

Objective-c-

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
 }
```

swift-

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

Comment: It kinda works, but now there's a black gap instead of the status bar:  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=768cf89e7cf13325!4439&authkey=!AI6RsI-Nc4DSBwY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: Hi @RamyAlZuhouri , Please try edited code. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Add UISearchControllerDelegate;

Then

```
-(void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
_tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 44, 0);}
```