# How can I lower the writings in the option bar with UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: cocoa

I'm using this to initialize the document view.

```
NSString * filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Document_%d",key];
NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:filename withExtension:@"pdf"];
if (URL) {
  // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
  self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];
  [self.documentInteractionController setUTI:@"com.adobe.pdf"];
  // Configure Document Interaction Controller
  [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
  // Preview PDF
  [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
```

It works, this is the screen.
[image]

My problem is that the writings are too high. How can I lower it a little bit?
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This is where I find the solution. You have 2 choices:

```
//First solution
//This shows the whole status bar
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

//Second solution from the link below
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller
{
  //This hide the status bar completely
  [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelStatusBar];

    return [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
}
```

[Hide status bar when using UIDocumentInteractionController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770804/hide-status-bar-when-using-uidocumentinteractioncontroller)

This is because, by default the bar is not properly setted.