# status bar hidden on simulator but not iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm presenting a navigation controller with a view controller embedded in it and i want the status bar to be hidden. The good news is the status bar is hidden on simulator. But its not hidden when I test it on the actual iPhone. Here is my code.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login:SIgnUp", bundle: nil)
                if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Welcome") as? WelcomeVC {
                    vc.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
                    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
                    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
```

Comment: You never hide status bar. You can hide navigation controller only.

Comment: @dahiya_boy thats not true

Answer (score 1):

Write this method on each view controller unless you have that plist entry.

Objective-c

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

Swift 3+

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

And don't forget to set (if you present a view controller by calling the presentViewController:animated:completion: method):

Objective-C

```
vcToBeShownWithoutStatusbar.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = YES;
```

Swift

```
vcToBeShownWithoutStatusbar.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in **viewWillAppear:**

```
UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: .slide)
```

And if you don’t want to hide status bar for other views then you should hide in **viewWillDisappear:**

```
UIApplication.shared.setStatusBarHidden(false, with: .slide)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

for more option you can go [Status Bar Hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236912/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-a-swift-ios-app)