# IOS - storyboard|xib How do I set the status bar to hide

Tags: ios

I want to explore the development of xib| storyboard, the details of the status bar hidden, and finally related blog, thanks。

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide the status bar in a Swift iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236912/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-a-swift-ios-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide iOS status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/how-to-hide-ios-status-bar)