# Hide Status Bar in iOS 13

Tags: swift, uistatusbar

Hiding Status Bar using the usual way doesn't work because the method is deprecated.
[image]

The status bar has to be hidden in one view controller, but not all of them. How can I hide/show it programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide the status bar in a Swift iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236912/how-do-i-hide-the-status-bar-in-a-swift-ios-app)

Comment: Look at this [link](https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-ios13-in-cocos-2dx/48026)

Comment: you also need to go to project->General->Status Bar Style
set it to requires fullscreen and hidestatus bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1 :- add permission

[image]

Step 2 :- add the below code in desired view controller to hide the status bar .

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
     return true
}
```

NOTE :- if you don't set constrain properly after the hidden true / false you will have design issues , so take care about it  ...:)

Comment: is anyone found solution for this ios 13 status bar hide. I still facing this error please help me to rectify this error.

Answer (score 3):

just **adding** to the accepted answer, if your controller is embedded in a stack like how it was for me then you need an extra piece of code as well and be sure to provide this in/before the controller loads.

```
extension UINavigationController {
open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return topViewController?.prefersStatusBarHidden ?? true
}
```

}

then call this where you want to update

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```