# Hiding the Status bar in a particular view controller, in a TabbarViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar, tabbar

I have a `TabbarViewController`. In one tab, when navigating to a specific `ViewController` (a details image view), I want to hide the status bar.
I have read this link:
[How to hide a status bar in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661031/how-to-hide-a-status-bar-in-ios/18953677#18953677)

But in my case, it doesn't work, because I don't want to hide the status bar in the whole app, but just in a specific `ViewController`.

Is there a way to acheive hiding the scrollbar only in a certain tab?

*Edit:
The ViewController I want to hide status bar is a PageViewController. Is that the problem?

Comment: I just edited your question so it's easier to understand what exactly you're asking. I hope I understood the question correctly :).

Comment: try this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/how-to-hide-ios-7-status-bar

Comment: @ Lea Cohen: Thank you so much, my English is not good. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewDidAppear:YES];
        if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]){
            [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
            [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        }
        else{
            // iOS 6
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        }

    }
    else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
            [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
        }
        else{
            // iOS 6
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        }
    }
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But it still doesn't work. And the ViewController I want to hide the status bar is a PageViewController, is that the problem?

Comment: write down only these three function in which u want to hide.

Comment: @ Pratik Patel: I do exactly what you said, but it doesn't work... I just see the status bar style change

Comment: are you using greate than iOS 7?

Comment: I use both iOS 6.0 and higher

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
}
```